# Create a scrollable container for a table without fixed size that also prevents scroll bars on parent elements including browser window

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Desired output:

- The red div (`table-container`) will display vertical / horizontal scroll bars around the table it contains.
- No scroll bars will appear on the browser window or parent element.

Actual output:

- Horizontal and vertical scroll bars are displayed on the browser window as well as the `table-container` div.
- Height of the table is not constrained.

Solutions I would like to avoid:

- Placing a fixed height/width on `table-container`.  Note that `body` is constrained to 100vh/vw.
- Attempting to modify the table i.e. using something like `table-layout`.

Edit:
Table height and width are specified in this example html only to illustrate the problem. In my application I have no control over the size of the table and it is quite large.

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <style>

    body, html {
        height:100vh;
        width:100vw;
        max-height:100vh;
        max-width:100vw;
        display:flex;
        flex:1;
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
    }


    footer {
        display:flex;
        height: 10vh;
        min-height: 10vh;
        background-color:#666666;
    }

    .page 
    {
        display:flex;
        flex:1 1 auto;
        flex-direction:row;
    }

    .side-nav {
      display: flex;
      flex:0 1 auto;
      flex-flow: column;
      width:20vw;
      min-width:20vw;
      height:100vh;
      min-height:100vh;
      background-color:#99ccff;
    }

    .content {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction:column;
      flex:1 1 auto;
      background-color:#cccccc;
    }

    .col-layout {
        display:flex;
        flex:1 1 auto;
        flex-direction:column;
    }

    .table-container {
        display:flex;
        flex-direction:column;
        overflow-x:scroll;
        overflow-y:scroll;
        margin:3%;
        background-color:red;
        width:90%;
        max-width:90%;
        height:90%;
        max-height:90%;
    }



    table {
        margin:3%;
        width:1500px;
        height:2000px;
        background-color:#3399ff;
    }

    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="page">
      <div class="side-nav">
        <label>Side Nav</label>
      </div>

      <div class="col-layout">
          <div class="content">
            <label>Content</label>
            <label>The red div should have vertical and horizontal scroll bars - no vertical or horizontal scroll bars should appear on the browser window.</label>
            <div class="table-container">
                <table>
                    <tr><td>key</td><td>value</td></tr>
                </table>
            </div>
          </div>
            
          <footer>
            <label>Footer</label>
          </footer>
      </div>
    </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Prevent the size of the table from affecting the size of its flex item ancestors by setting their `min-width` and `min-height` to something else than `auto`.**

The reason you’re getting scrollbars on the browser window right now is that the ancestors of your table—`.table-container`, `.col-layout`—are flex items, and [flex items derive their minimum size from their content](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-flexbox/#min-size-auto) by default. So if the content is a huge table (and it’s huge because it has lots of content, or because we explicitly set `width` and/or `height`), then the flex items up your element hierarchy will try to “protect” this size.

We can confirm this by looking at the Firefox DevTools layout inspector:
[image]

This behavior can be changed by setting [`min-width`](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/min-width) or [`min-height`](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/min-height). The initial value is `auto`, and that’s what leads to this content-derived sizing in Flexbox. So, for example, if you have a flex container with `flex-direction: row`, you’ll want to change `min-width` from `auto` to something else.

In our case, we want to completely ignore the size of our `table`. So we’ll set `min-width` and `min-height` to `0` for all elements where `table` could affect their size.

Here’s a working example:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
}

nav {
  padding: 32px;
  background-color: bisque;
}

section {
  flex: auto;
  min-width: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

main {
  flex: auto;
  min-height: 0;
  padding: 8px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

footer {
  padding: 24px;
  background-color: burlywood;
}

.table-container {
  flex: auto;
  min-height: 0;
  background-color: tomato;
  padding: 16px;
  overflow: auto;
}

table {
  width: 1500px;
  height: 2000px;
  background-color: steelblue;
  border: 10px solid white;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <nav>Side nav</nav>
  <section>
    <main>
      <h1>Content with the table container</h1>
      <div class="table-container">
        <table>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th colspan="2">The table header</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>The table body</td>
              <td>with two columns</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </main>
    <footer>Footer</footer>
  </section>
</body>
```

Comment: You color coordination is as impressive as your mastery of css.  Superb.  Thanks much.

Answer (score 0):

The thing that you wanted to do is possible if you give `height/width` of `.table-container` in either `vh` units or hard code like `px,cm,em` .

- But the way you want to do is not possible because if you give measurements in soft code then the container will adapt to the the width of of table and it will also effect to those whose width is not specified and renders to the width of table

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  max-height: 100vh;
  max-width: 100vw;
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

footer {
  display: flex;
  height: 10vh;
  min-height: 10vh;
  background-color: #666666;
}

.page {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.side-nav {
  display: flex;
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  flex-flow: column;
  width: 20vw;
  min-width: 20vw;
  height: 100vh;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-color: #99ccff;
}

.content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  background-color: #cccccc;
}

.col-layout {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.table-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  margin: 3%;
  background-color: red;
  width: 120vh;
  height: 60vh;
}

table {
  margin: 3%;
  width: 1500px;
  height: 2000px;
  background-color: #3399ff;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>

</head>

<body>
  <div class="page">
    <div class="side-nav">
      <label>Side Nav</label>
    </div>

    <div class="col-layout">
      <div class="content">
        <label>Content</label>
        <label>The red div should have vertical and horizontal scroll bars - no vertical or horizontal scroll bars should appear on the browser window.</label>

        <div class="table-container">
          <table>
            <tr>
              <td>key</td>
              <td>value</td>

            </tr>
          </table>
        </div>

      </div>

      <footer>
        <label>Footer</label>
      </footer>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

See effect in full page

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I neglected to mention in my original question that I provided height/width of the table for example purposes only.  In my application I can not constrain with size of the table.

Comment: What you want to do it is not clear .You want scroll bars to table only or what

Comment: Scroll bars only on the red div.  Not the browser window, not a parent element.

Comment: Changed the code see if that work for you

Comment: Just change color if you need . I also added a border to show that table can be bordered irrespective of scrolls

Comment: It is not possible for me to set height/width on the table.  I provided a large height/width in the example to demonstrate the fact the red div is not showing scroll bars correctly.

Comment: The thing that you want to do is only possible when you specify `.table-container` width in `vh or px` else you want to violate the CSS which is not possible .This is the last answer modification. Have a good day ahead